# Why can a char array be used in a constexpr function template but not in a static_assert

Tags: c++, templates, static-assert

I have a `constexpr` function template which takes a `char` array, the bounds of which are known at compile time:

```
template<size_t N>
constexpr bool check(const char (&arr)[N], size_t n = 0)
```

I can use this function with a string literal in a `static_assert` call.

In this function I can walk through the string literal and perform calculations at compile time on the individual characters which make up the string.

However, if I have another `constexpr` function template which also takes a char array / string literal

```
template<size_t N>
constexpr void test(const char (&arr)[N])
```

and from within that function I call `static_assert`, `arr` is no longer a constant expression, and so the `static_assert` is not allowed.

Given the string literal's bounds are known at compile time, and it is therefore a statically sized array, and `size_t N` is a template parameter, I would have thought it should be possible to use `arr` in function `test`.

It is not possible to call `test` with a non-constant array, so I would expect the compiler to know that `arr` is constant in `test`.

Attempting to call `test` with a non-constant array results in a different (expected) error:

```
main.cpp:16:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:32:15: note:   mismatched types ‘const char [N]’ and ‘const char*’
```

### Question:

**Why can I use `const char (&arr)[N]` *inside* a `static_assert`, but not pass it *to* a `static_assert`?**

### Full example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>

template<size_t N>
constexpr bool check(const char (&arr)[N], size_t n = 0)
{
    return
        n >= N ?
            true
        : arr[n] != '*' ?
            check(arr, n + 1)
        : throw std::logic_error("arr can't contain a '*'");
}

template<size_t N>
constexpr void test(const char (&arr)[N])
{
    static_assert(check<N>(arr), ""); // non-constant condition for static assertion
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(check("foo"), "");

    // fails to compile: string contains '*'
    //static_assert(check("foo*"), ""); 

    // fails to compile: ‘arr’ is not a constant expression
    //test("foo"); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `constexpr` on a function doesn't mean "this function can only be called with arguments known at compile time", or "this function is always executed at compile time". It means "if parameters happen to be compile-time constants, then the function can be executed at compile time and so the function call is itself a compile-time constant". It is legal to pass arguments to a `constexpr` function that are not in fact compile-time constants; then it runs like any regular function would.

Comment: Yes I know that - I'm asking why passing a string literal to `check` *can* be used in a `static_assert` but passing a string literal to `test` causes it to degrade from a constant that can be used in `static_assert` to non-constant which can't

Comment: Because, again, for all the compiler knows, your program may be calling `test` and passing a non-constant, dynamically computed `char` array to it.

Comment: But given `test` is a function template, `N` has to be known at compile time, so `arr` *has to be* a constant array surely?

Comment: [Not really](http://rextester.com/OCXH54470). Not a compile-time constant. It's only a constant in `const` sense (can't be modified after having been initialized), not necessarily in `constexpr` sense (fully known at compile-time).

Comment: @Steve: It may help to realize there is only one version of `test` for each `N`: both `test("boo")` and `test("ya*")` call the same function. And so does `char foo[3]; /* set the contents of foo at runtime */ test(foo);`.

Comment: Ah yes, and I suppose I could call `test<4>(var)` with a runtime `char*` variable, and the function call would work, but the `static_assert` could of course not.

Comment: @Hurkyl if you'd like to write your comment as an answer I'd gladly accept it